# What makes geeks tick?

Tags: discussion

Apparently we have all been the objects of a scientific study:

> Many online platforms such as Yahoo! Answers and GitHub rely on users to voluntarily provide content. What motivates users to contribute content for free however is not well understood.
>
> In this paper, we use a revealed preference approach to show that career concerns play an important role in user contributions to Stack Overflow, the largest online Q&A community. We investigate how activities that can enhance a user’s reputation vary before and after the user finds a new job. We contrast this with activities that do not help in enhancing a user’s reputation.
>
> After finding a new job, users contribute 25% less in reputation-generating activity on Stack Overflow. By contrast, they reduce their non-reputation-generating activity by only 8% after finding a new job. These findings suggest that users contribute to Stack Overflow in part because they perceive this as a way to improve future employment prospects.
>
> We provide direct evidence against alternative explanations such as integer constraints, skills mismatch, and dynamic selection effects. The results also suggest that, beyond altruism, career concerns play an important role in explaining voluntary contributions on Stack Overflow.

Thats the abstract of ["What Makes Geeks Tick? A Study of Stack Overflow Careers"](http://leixu.org/Xu_JMP_Stack_Overflow.pdf), a paper by economists
Lei Xu, Tingting Nian and Luís Cabral. If you want a TL;DR of the abstract, I think the last sentence is the interesting take home message here: "users contribute to Stack Overflow in part because they perceive this as a way to improve future employment prospects".

My question to you all is this: Do you think the conclusion is correct, in general as well for yourself personally? I know this will only be a collection of anecdotes that hardly trumps the hard data, but it would still be interesting to hear some thoughts about this paper.

Comment: As fun a conversation as this might be... not sure meta's the place for it....

Comment: Are there some people that post for that reason, sure, is it a compelling reason for a large portion of the active user base, I highly doubt it.

Comment: I would say no, but, subconsciously i may be wrong.

Comment: Indirectly, it is correct in that i originally (and still do a little) contributed to SO as a means of gaining knowledge, which of course would improve my chances of future employment.

Comment: I have always been under the impression that those who are on SO *mainly* because of future career prospects aren't part of what might be called the "hard core" of site users (who edit, review, and participate in Meta, things that don't pay off cold, hard rep).

Comment: A discussion seeking input from folks on SO *about* their participation on SO seems meta-y enough.

Comment: @Patrice I was a bit unsure if it would be on-topic, but I recalled a highly upvoted meta post from a new user on why people spent so much time, energy and effort on this site. I thought that was a good predescent, but I cant seem to find it now, so perhaps my memory is fooling me. I will consider deleting this question if it continues to acumulate downvotes.

Comment: @Anders I may be wrong. I mean, Shog seems to say it is meta :P. I don't mind either way, this is a conversation I'll follow :P

Comment: Maybe it would help if the question was refocused to SO itself: whether this effect should be exploited or mitigated, and how?

Comment: I find my participation increases dramatically when I try to pick up a new language as I'm searching more which leads to answering (and asking) more questions. I'd be interested if there was some geographic breakdown on it too.

Comment: Related: [Academic papers using Stack Exchange data](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134495/134300)

Comment: The non-geeky people are pretty fascinated about it, they want to push more geek buttons and get them to solve their problems for free.  What they don't really understand is that it requires the kind of geek that's comfortable about the idea he has to re-invent everything he knows every five years.  Without any support from the people that hire him.  Locked up in a crappy cubicle with absolutely no chance for career development.  Dumped when he's 40-somehing.  But still liking what he does a lot.  So much so that he spends his free time to learn what needs to be learned.

Comment: @Hans your bleak poetry often scares me. :) But you're right on. `they want to push more geek buttons and get them to solve their problems for free` this should be framed.

Comment: I just assumed everyone was addicted.. like crack. When you don't have that much money (or in this case time), you buy less crack.

Comment: Based on the comments, I think geeks are like clocks.  To make them tick all you have to do is wind them up...

Comment: Alternatively, people could just be here because they simply want to. Like me. SO is a good place for learning new things.

Comment: Face it: SO is a never ending source of procrastination.

Comment: People use SO in part for future employment prospects? I could have told you that without a study.

Comment: Clearly... we contribute because of internet points.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They say it takes 10,000 hours of practice to master a skill. Stack Overflow - by presenting me with a steady flow of new ideas, helps me get that practice.

I answer on SO; therefore I become better at my areas of expertise.

This naturally has career benefits - both in my current job,  because I can do more, but also opening up prospects that might not otherwise be available - this is especially true in IT when you're looking to switch niche - if you've a lot of experience as a sysadmin, making the leap to a programmer is (most likely!) going to result in some amount of backtracking - because you won't have been gaining experience at the 1 year per year rate of someone who's been working as a programmer.

Stack Overflow is a way to mitigate this - perhaps not entirely, but to an extent. So if I am looking to alter areas of specialisation, I'm not walking into an interview as a junior because I just don't have the basic skills. You perhaps don't have the same experience ratio as someone who's been programming (although you may do, because you have a much greater diversity of problems to have practiced with)

That's my professional motivation for being here (Doubly so because I can -also- keep up with other skill areas via Unix & Linux or ServerFault).

But at the end of the day, I find problem solving satisfying. That's my major reason for being here.

Comment: Last paragraph kind of says it all. Amen.

Comment: Agreed, it's the last paragraph that is the key. SO users enjoy solving problems and when they have a new job they get a whole stream of new interesting problems delivered to them so they don't need to seek out interesting problems to solve elsewhere - in other words, their Problem Solving Activity Threshold gets met naturally in their new job so they participate less in solving problems on SO.

Answer (score 59):

I've noticed a drop in my own participation when I pick up new jobs/contracts, but that usually has more to do with time than with motives.

Basically when I have more/new paid work, I have less time to contribute.

My moderation activities usually suffer less because they don't require as much time or thought as answers.

This may be an alternative explanation for the observed trend in the study.

Comment: I like your answer and would like to add, that - as a Junior Developer - after starting a new Job there is so much new stuff to learn. In the first 2-3 months there is so much input I am just exhausted after work and don't want to think about code anymore.

Comment: It's not that hard to contribute with answers. For example, if you got stuck with something on your work and have found a solution for it by yourself, you can google the question for that solution e.g. "How to do that and that". You can easily check if someone has the same problem and post your solution if nobody helped him already.

Answer (score 18):

My reputation-generating activity certainly dropped when I took a new position a couple years ago, but that was for two primary reasons:

1. My new job required a different skill set then what I was used to. While in my previous position I was pretty near the apex of my very small niche, in my new position I have a lot to learn and much less to share. Which leads to #2...
2. My new job is much more interesting and demanding than my old job, which is why I switched in the first place. In my previous job there was a lot of downtime and a lot of stress, providing opportunity and motivation to find an outlet. In my new job, I don't have as much downtime (I consider this a positive) and there's a lot less stress, so there's not been as much opportunity or motivation to post as there once was.

I will say this, though: my reputation on SO had absolutely 0 impact on my being hired, nor did I think it would have a significant impact. If I ever had career as my motivation for posting, I don't remember it. It wasn't a significant reason for participating... I participate because it's fun.

Comment: I have had a similar experience. I've had jobs that were boring a monotonous, those jobs I spent most of my time contributing to SO. When I have left those jobs for more intriguing opportunities I spent less time on SO because I get that experience at the workplace.

Comment: Same for me + I recently moved into a new home due to a new job. A new home means additional work for months. :)

Answer (score 9):

In order to be relevant in this field, it is required to stay aware of new technology.

One of the best ways to learn is to answer questions because it does often require a lot of research.

I am not sure how any of those two issues got caught up in analyzing career timing, but without at least some rate of learning, we would all end up like this guy

[image]

Which no one wants...

What makes us tick? Unicorns, waffles, and rainbows. And hats. And sometimes good food, or at least a beer.

Comment: I want to be that guy; he has a cool phone!

Comment: What do you have against Dom Joly?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR - Nothing. What do you have against modern phones?

Answer (score 7):

So I took an unscientific peek at the scientific study. It says that it is focusing on "job switchers":

> Job switchers: the change in the level of career concerns comes from a
>   job switch; we select users who experienced a job change from November
>   2008 until November 2014, the month when we stopped collecting data.
>   To focus on job switches, we require the gap between two jobs are less
>   or equal to one month.

However, the paper fails to define what a "job switch" is. Is it some script on the Career site that defines a job switch or is it them scientists? I cannot tell from the report.

Even more interesting: what is the definition of a "job" on the Careers site? Is unemployed a job? Student? Part-time? Running your own company (with variable work-load)?

If the study only proves that unemployed/less busy people have more free time to spend on SO than full-time employed, I'm afraid it failed to blow my mind.

Comment: (1) A job is a job; a gap between jobs is not a job. (2) The paper is not examining whether having a job affects how *much* you use SO, but *how* your time on SO is spent before and after a job switch. In the footnote right after your quote, they explain that they are also working on the "unemployed to employed" transition but are not ready to report anything yet.

Comment: @Frank The problem is that they haven't defined the term "a job" in their study, so it could be anything.

Comment: My guess: You have a job if your "Experience" section ends in "-current" for a single entry. You have a different job if and when that "-current" entry changes. The only ambiguity would come from people with multiple "-current" entries in that section, and I'm guessing they dropped 'em. There are not many other ways to read "job" than the common English meaning, even in labor economics.

Comment: @Frank Then it would certainly count all students as "having a job". Anyway, we shouldn't have to guess, if the scientific study is properly done. Perhaps this definition is found somewhere in the study and I was simply not able to find it.

Comment: I mean, if anything, the problem is that your guesses do not seem reasonable. There is a separate section for education, so no reason to confuse "(Job) Experience" and "Education". I agree that it could be spelled out better how they deal with edge cases (like holding two positions at once or changing positions within a firm), but it's still a work-in-progress paper. Also, no one is claiming this is "scientific" in the paper itself or the world it circulates in -- we're talking social science here, basically just statistics.

Answer (score 2):

For most of us, it's gears that make us tick. Use the little windup key and you get us going every time :)

As a startup founder, I do not look at SO as a way of finding employment prospects - I genuinely need the information here to get past technical hurdles. When I post it's out of gratitude for the platform and to give back where I can.

Answer (score 1):

I only come on here to either help where I can or, more likely, to get assistance - if I wanted to waste my time on online activities to allegedly 'boost my career prospects' I'd be working LinkedIn and rehashing content from elsewhere on the interwebs in th same vaguelyt meaningless way that many on there seem to. The time that I spend on the various Stack Exchange sites is related more to free time and whether I'm actively engaged in something on here at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Anecdotal counterevidence yay !

When I was 'happy' at my previous job, I got to about 70 Imaginary Internet Points.

While I was looking for something else, which means the lead-up to my current job, I earned exactly 0 IIP.

Since I've been where I am now, I've slowly but steadily accumulated 400 IIP.

Of course it helps that my current company is very SO-minded and encourages its technical employees to participate - not only on its own tags but on whatever interests us.

So if at some point I stop contributing for a while, I guess my bosses might expect my resignation letter.

Answer (score 1):

There have been enough questions on meta where people mistakenly think that reputation is a measure of how knowledgeable you are that it makes sense that folks think it enhances their job prospects. (FWIW, I'm not saying it doesn't.)

But as I said in a different meta question a while back, down-voting is, for the most part, the easiest, fastest way to contribute to the site. Anything else, even just voting up, takes more time because it requires you to examine the post more. The only thing that's just as fast as down voting an obviously bad question is flagging obvious spam.

So yes, the rep generating activity takes a hit after you get a job because anything that generates rep *takes more time*. Not to mention that the easiest rep generating activity, editing posts, stops giving you rep after you get 1000 rep from it (or hit 2000 rep overall).